# Hard times with IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle, python-2.5

So I've been working with Python on my computer for about the last 2 months with no issues. Just recently however, something went wrong with IDLE. I am running python 2.5

I used to be able to right-click and select "Edit with IDLE" for a python program. That option no longer is available. When I try "open with" and navigate to the idlelib in python, I can select idle.bat, idle.py, or idle.py (no console). I've tried each option and each fails to open and returns an error that either it is not a valid Win32 application or that "Windows cannot find idle.pyw"

I am able to open IDLE on its own and use the open function in IDLE to open files, but can't open files directly using IDLE as I could before.

There was formerly the White background icon with the python logo, which is now replace by windows' logo for no program (white square, blue and red dots). I have tried to repair-install and unistall-re-install both with no success. There is no firewall or antivirus, and it was installed with permissions for all users.

Any help is much appreciated, this has been maddeningly difficult to figure out.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. IDLE is awful and you shouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: I see your point, but I'm a rookie programmer and I'm troubleshooting the problems here. I think the IDLE troubles is as much a symptom as a cause. When I open with IDLE, the programs still can't find anything associated with it, like Tkinter for example

Is there a workaround you would suggest?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using such an *ancient* version of Python? Install 2.7.8 if you must use Python 2, or 3.4.1 for Py3.

Comment: Search your Python installation directory for `idle.py` and tell us what you find. Mine is in `c:\Python27\Lib\idlelib\idle.py`

Comment: I get Syntax Error: unexpected character after line continuation character and a pointer to the y in idle.py

Comment: I'm using 2.5 because I'm working with a previously written program, that was developed 5 years ago using (you guessed it) 2.5

Answer (score 0):

The native one that comes with python on windows is problematic at times, so you could uninstall and reinstall it as a solution, or open it from its directory instead of a shortcut, or get another IDE. I recommend the Ninja IDE very nice and light looking, or if you're on linux you could just use vim from terminal.

Also, if it's extremely necessary, try upgrading your python version and IDE. I think the IDE included for windows looks like a modified emacs to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that *Windows* changed the right-context menu for .py files has nothing to do with Idle, and probably nothing to do with Python either.  You are not the first to have this problem.  You can potentially restore 'Edit with Idle' but without directly editing the registry (an expert option) I only knew how to do so in XP. You might also be able to fix it be going back to a restore point before it changed, but you would lose all updates since, so I would not do that.

I am surprised that re-installing did not restore it.  The line was once gone for me, too, and was restored by a recent install.

I have Win7. I just now tried 'Open with', navigated to 3.4 idlelib, and selected idle.bat (the .py files were not offered as a choice).  The .py file opened in an Idle editor just fine.  It is now a permanent option for Open with, without having to navigate.

Idle has gotten perhaps 150 patches since 2.5.  Even if you have to edit programs to run on 2.5, I strongly recommend installing a current version of Python and Idle.

I have no ideal what your comment "the programs still can't find anything associated with it, like Tkinter for example " means.